# change image use javascript DOM

Tags: javascript, image, dom, function

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var curimage = "cottage_small.jpg";   
var curtext = "View large image"; 
function changeSrc() { 
    if (curtext == "View large image"||curimage == "cottage_small.jpg") { 
        document.getElementById("boldStuff").innerHTML = "View small image"; 
        curtext="View small image"; 
        document.getElementById("myImage")= "cottage_large.jpg"; 
        curimage = "cottage_large.jpg";
    } else { 
        document.getElementById("boldStuff").innerHTML = "View large image"; 
        curtext = "View large image"; 
        document.getElementById("myImage")= "cottage_small.jpg"; 
        curimage = "cottage_small.jpg"; 
    } 
} 
</script> 
</head>
<body> 
    <!-- Your page here --> 
    <h1> Pink Knoll Properties</h1>
    <h2> Single Family Homes</h2> 
    <p>
        Cottage:<strong>$149,000</strong><br/>
        2 bed, 1 bath, 1,189 square feet, 1.11 acres <br/><br/> 
        <a href="#" onclick="changeSrc()"><b id="boldStuff" />View large image</a>
    </p>  
    <p><img id="myImage" src="cottage_small.jpg" alt="Photo of a cottage"  /></p> 
</body>
</html>
```

This is my coding I need to change the image and text the same time when I click it.

I use LTS, it shows the line `document.getElementById("myImage")= "cottage_large.jpg";`

is a wrong number of arquments or invalid property assigment.

Dose someone can help?

Bianca

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do the following steps

1. Change  **document.getElementById("myImage")** to  **document.getElementById("myImage").src**
2. Change <b id="boldStuff" />View large image to <b id="boldStuff">View large image</b>

This will solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to change the image *source*.

```
document.getElementById("myImage").src = "cottage_large.jpg";
```

Comment: I change it but still wrong, it shows:  document.getElementById() is null or not an object.

Answer (score 1):

You should change :-

```
<b id="boldStuff" />View large image
```

to following:-

```
<b id="boldStuff">View large image</b>
```

Looks like the getElementById does not work well for empty tags If you dont use ending tag.

Complete correct source:-

```
<html> 
<head> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var curimage = "cottage_small.jpg";    
var curtext = "View large image";  
function changeSrc() {  
    if (curtext == "View large image"||curimage == "cottage_small.jpg") {  
        document.getElementById("boldStuff").innerHTML = "View small image";  
        curtext="View small image";  
        document.getElementById("myImage").src= "cottage_large.jpg";  
        curimage = "cottage_large.jpg"; 
    } else {  
        document.getElementById("boldStuff").innerHTML = "View large image";  
        curtext = "View large image";  
        document.getElementById("myImage").src= "cottage_small.jpg";  
        curimage = "cottage_small.jpg";  
    }  
}  
</script>  
</head> 
<body>  
    <!-- Your page here -->  
    <h1> Pink Knoll Properties</h1> 
    <h2> Single Family Homes</h2>  
    <p> 
        Cottage:<strong>$149,000</strong><br/> 
        2 bed, 1 bath, 1,189 square feet, 1.11 acres <br/><br/>  
        <a href="#" onclick="changeSrc()"><b id="boldStuff">View large image</b></a> 
    </p>   
    <p><img id="myImage" src="cottage_small.jpg" alt="Photo of a cottage"  /></p>  
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

KooiInc is correct. but there is one problem with this statement.

**IE6** will not honour **document.getElementById("myImage").src**.

so i suggest you use jquery instead like this.

**$('#myImage').attr("src","the new source path");**

**Update**:

@CMS: Please do check what i am tryin to say.

well i suppose there is a terrible misunderstanding here. for as far as i know IE6 never honours changing image source directly using **".src="** technique. I always used to use the following technique to achieve it if i can't use jquery.

```
document.getElementById('ImageId').style.cssText="filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='newPath');";
```

Comment: The `getElementById` method (introduced on DOM Level 2 standard, late 2000) and setting the `src` attribute will work even on IE5.